# Проверка строки на число в потоке

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, lambda

У меня `Map<String,String> map` может содержать в значении число в виде строки.
Я перебираю мапу циклом, проверяю регуляркой `value.matches("[-+]?\\d+"` и если это число - формирую новую мапу `Map<String,String> map2`.

А можно это сделать как нибудь с помощью лямбд из Java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, как-то так:

```
Map<String, String> map2 = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().matches("[-+]?\\d+"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```